# Delete s3 key - Python - doesn't work every run

Tags: python, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

In my Python function i am saving the results of an Athena query to an S3 bucket, then I need to copy it into Redshift.

I am using `boto3.client.get_query_execution`
when the results csv file is saved to an s3 bucket it saves it with the query id
for example: `s3://my-bucket/temp/31d84270-888d-406b-8b65-cabaa1c89184.csv`
and it also saves a metadata file like this:
`s3://my-bucket/temp/31d84270-888d-406b-8b65-cabaa1c89184.csv.metadata`
so when I try to copy the csv file it tries to copy both and fails as the metadata file is not compatible with the table + i don't need it.

I tried to delete the file before the copy occurs, with many many different options I found searching the web but they all didn't work, I can still see the file on s3 with no errors. some of the options worked once and then failed to delete the next 5 attempts (with no error msg for the delete part).

any suggestions?

Comment: Are objects versioned in your s3 bucket? You might have to delete the individual versions https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/DeletingObjectVersions.html

Comment: no its not versioned, but thanks !

Comment: You can control the files you copy to Redshift using a manifest file. Another option is to copy the CSV files that you want to another clean folder. Anyway, S3 is an eventual consistency service and it might take time for commands to take effect.

Comment: See this: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=244659